# React Native - Assign value from promise to variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, async-await, promise

I have a couple `repositories` containing database calls such as `getUser` and `getUsers`.
Now I export those repositories as followed:

```
import { DatabaseBackend } from "../common/database";
import {
    userRepository as _userRepository,
    bookingRepository as _bookingRepository,
    pricingRepository as _pricingRepository,
} from "../common/repositories";

const backend = DatabaseBackend.ReactNative;

export const userRepository = _userRepository(backend);
export const bookingRepository = _bookingRepository(backend);
export const pricingRepository = _pricingRepository(backend);
```

This leads to me having to do things like this:

```
const fetchUserData = (uid: string) => {
        userRepository
            .then((u) => {
                u.getUser(uid)
                    .then((user: User) => {
                        if(!user) {
                            return;
                        }

                        setUser(user);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        logger.error("Something went wrong while fetching user information", err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                logger.error("Something went wrong while fetching user information", err);
            });
    };
```

The intellisense says `userRepository` is:

```
const userRepository: Promise<{
    getUser: (id: string) => Promise<User>;
    getNanny: (id: string) => Promise<Nanny>;
    getNannies: () => Promise<Nanny[]>;
    getParent: (id: string) => Promise<Parent>;
    updateUser: (user: User) => Promise<void>;
}>
```

Is there a way how to assign the functions to `userRepository` without me having to do any `then` calls on it? I'd like to just being able to call `userRepository.getUser()` for example.

Comment: No, there's not. It's a promise, and the methods return promises, presumably because they do some asynchronous loading of data. You cannot make that immediately return a value.

Comment: Of course you can (and probably should) use `await` instead of `.then()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/await instead of `then`.

```
const fetchUserData = async (uid: string) => {
  try {
    const repo = await userRepository();
    const user: User = await repo.getUser(uid);
    if (!user) {
      return;
    }
    setUser(user);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("Something went wrong while fetching user information", err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. i would try and avoid having the `userRepository` coming from a Promise => try and have this resolved on some initialization phase of at least have memoization on its' value.
2. use `async/ await` as suggested here already.

Comment: I will look into it. Not sure how I'd do that. Thinking about maybe setting the repositories into some sort of context and initialize it there.